# [EDITED]Implementing Difference of Gaussian

Tags: c, opencv

I'm not sure if I'm doing the right way.

```
IplImage *dog_1 = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(oriImg), oriImg->depth, oriImg->nChannels);
IplImage *dog_2 = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(oriImg), oriImg->depth, oriImg->nChannels);

int kernel2 = 1;
int kernel1 = 5;

cvSmooth(oriImg, dog_2, CV_GAUSSIAN, kernel2, kernel2);
cvSmooth(oriImg, dog_1, CV_GAUSSIAN, kernel1, kernel1);
cvSub(dog_2, dog_1, dst, 0);
```

Am I doing the right way? Is the above the correct way of doing DOG? I just tried it from the explanation from wiki. But I could not get the desired image like in the wiki page http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Difference_of_Gaussians

[image: Difference of Gaussians]

[Edited]

I quote this from wiki page

"Difference of Gaussians is a grayscale image enhancement algorithm that involves the subtraction of one blurred version of an original grayscale image from another, less blurred version of the original. The blurred images are obtained by convolving the original grayscale image with Gaussian kernels having different standard deviations."

While reading a paper, the DoG image is done by

Original image, I(x,y) -> Blurs -> I1(x,y)

I1(x,y) -> Blurs -> I2(x,y)

output = I2(x,y) - I1(x,y)

As you see it's a slightly different from what I'm doing where I get the I1 and I2 using different kernel **from the original image**

Which one is the correct one or I misinterpret the meaning in the wiki?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the image you've attached is your sample output, it doesn't necessarily look wrong.  The DoG operation is quite simple: blur with two Gaussians of different sizes and compute the difference image.  That appears to be what your code is doing, so I'd say you have it right.

If your worries stem from looking at the Wikipedia article (where the image is predominantly white, rather than black), it is just the inversion of the image that you have.  I would not worry about that.

Comment: Thanks Chris. Using openCV, is that simple to perform DoG? I've searched and something related to octave. What is that anyway? Why do we need a few octave?

Comment: I support Chris's opinion about your worries with the sample pic: you just need to invert it, that's all, +1.